# How to check which cell in dataGridView is selected?

Tags: c#, select, datagridview

I'm want to send more than one mail from selected cells in dataGridView, but don't know how to find out which cells are selected, so the question is how to find out which cells are selected?

Can I make some loop to iterate through cells and test which cell are selected (checked)?

Language c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DataGridView.SelectedCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx) property.

```
foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView.SelectedCells)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection selectedCells = myDataGridView.SelectedCells;
```

See an example at: [How to: Get the Selected Cells, Rows, and Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx)

Comment: I will but at now i don't have much point to rate ... but shore i will as time go further

Comment: @John check here to see how to accept an answer. You don't need to have reputation to accept it.